# Rails query records where has_many count is greater then limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following:

```
class OfferClaim
 belongs_to :offer
end

class Offer
  has_many :offer_claims
  attr_accessible :claim_limit
end
```

And I need to be able to do something like this:

```
Offer.joins(:offer_claims).where("offer.claim_limit > offer_claims.count")
```

And only return the offers that have less associations then its limit.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect usage of `counter_cache`.

```
class OfferClaim
  belongs_to :offer, :counter_cache => true
end
```

This would increment an `offer_claim_count` column on the `offers` table whenever a new `OfferClaim` is created (and decrement it when it's deleted).

Then your query would be:

```
Offer.where("offer.claim_limit > offer_claims_count")
```

No `joins` statement required.

Comment: Yeah, I really don't want to use counter cache as that will mean every time a claim occurs it is updating the offer and thus clearing the cache.

Comment: What do you mean "clearing the cache"? Nothing is being cleared here, it's either incrementing or decrementing.

Comment: I have sweepers that cache the claim object as it doesn't change that often. Now if we use a counter cache the object will be updated 46,000 times potentially. That is way to many and will not hold up.